# How to detect an ip belongs to a particular state of USA

Tags: php, geolocation

I am developing a chat application in which a model can ban some state of USA so that user from that state can't chat with that model.What is the simplest way to detect that an  ip/user belongs to a particular state of USA.

Comment: Look up where IPs *"belong to"* and evaluate your client's IP. What's the actual question?

Comment: Find a IP to Country / state database, install it and use it.

Comment: You should state your main goal, what you expect to happen, what is actually happening and what you've tried.

Comment: Simplest way? A database full of I.P ranges that correlate to particular states.

Comment: You can download the free geolocation database such as http://lite.ip2location.com and then remove all records from Non-US. If an range match the remaining records, then it must be from USA.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-services-and-databases .

Please note that no IP address is geographically bound. It just does not work this way. I can get myself an IP address which belongs to another country all together. So I can circumvent your application ban with ease.

There simply no reliable way to map IP to physical location. Guys from MaxMind used number of techniques to collect this data and at the moment it is only known publicly available geo ip database with good coverage.

Comment: Thanks.I am using http://www.geoplugin.net which is free and  it internally using maxmind.Shall i use this?